# Call objective c++ method from objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c++

I'm just learning Objective C (and objective-c++ for that matter) and I have an Objective-C++ class with the following constructor.

```
void InputManager::_init (int inputAreaX, int inputAreaY, int inputAreaWidth, int inputAreaHeight)
```

How do I invoke this from objective C?

Comment: The same way you would in C++

Comment: you mean...like 
    instanceOfInputManager->_init(0, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: because that doesn't work either

Comment: Then you need to provide more info about what you did

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a pure C++ method so it would work exactly the same as in ordinary C++ (even in an Objective-C++ file).  For instance you might have defined a variable on the stack:

```
InputManager mgr; // or, include constructor arguments if the class can't be default-constructed
mgr._init(x, y, w, h); // this assumes 4 variables exist with these names; use whatever parameter values you want
```

The name `_init` is a bit weird though; do you mean for this to be a constructor for the class?  If so, `InputManager::InputManager(int x, int y, int w, int h)` should probably be defined instead.

If you actually want this class to be *Objective-C only*, the syntax and behavior are different.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

**Option 1.**

Translate it into Objective-C only code. I'm not so good with C++, but this might be what it looks like in the .h:

```
-(id)initWithAreaX: (int) inputAreaX AreaY: (int) inputAreaY AreaWidth: (int) inputAreaWidth AreaHeight: (int) inputAreaHeight;
```

Since it looks like that's a constructor method, it would probably look like this in the implementation:

```
-(id)initWithAreaX: (int) inputAreaX AreaY: (int) inputAreaY AreaWidth: (int) inputAreaWidth AreaHeight: (int) inputAreaHeight {

    self = [super init];

    if(self) {

        //Custom Initialization Code Here    
        _inputAreaX = inputAreaX;
        _inputAreaY = inputAreaY;
        _inputAreaWidth = inputAreaWidth;
        _inputAreaHeight = inputAreaHeight;
    }

    return self;
}
```

And you might call it like this:

```
InputManager *object = [[InputManager alloc] initWithAreaX: 20 AreaY: 20 AreaWidth: 25 AreaHeight: 25];
```

**Option 2.**

The whole purpose of Objective-C++ is to allow the developer to integrate C++ and Objective-C code. You want to know how to call an Objective-C++ method from Objective-C, but the entire purpose of Objective-C++ is to integrate the two, so there's no point to trying to find a loophole to call an Objective-C++ method in a file that is otherwise completely Objective-C. So the second option is to just make the file that you want to call the Objective-C++ method in an Objective-C++ file with a ".mm" extension.

Hope this helps!